# How to scroll a resultset from an ODBC datasource using cursors in PowerShell?

Tags: sql, powershell, odbc

How do I use a cursor to scroll a resultset from an ODBC datasource in PowerShell ?

**Problem:**

The SQL statement takes too long to execute (due to returning millions of rows). I only want to return the top 5 rows but this database does not support the `top`, `limit` or `rownum` select statement clauses).

Current code (that does not use cursors):

```
$datasourceName = "big_database"

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * as 'millions_of_rows' FROM big_table"

$odbcConnection = new-object Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$odbcConnection.ConnectionString = "dsn=$datasourceName"
$odbcConnection.open() 

$resultSet = (new-object Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($sqlQuery, $odbcConnection)).ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
$table.Load($resultSet)

#/* Display results */
$table
```

Comment: You have a datatable (part of the dataset).  So scroll through the datatable.

Comment: @jdweng The issue is the SQL statement takes too long to execute (millions of rows returned). So would be better to open a cursor to retrieve the first couple of rows. (I have updated the question with this requirement).

Comment: You are correct.  Did you consider using Raw SQL.  Powershell is built on c# so any c# code can be converted to powershell.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries  Raw SQL will allow you to use top, limit or rownum